# how to make Google Chrome use a specific java plugin

Tags: java, google-chrome, plugins, windows-7

I have 2 java versions installed (32-bit java 6 and 64-bit java 7) on my PC, I need the Google Chrome to use the 64-bit java 7 instead it keeps showing 32-bit java 6 in the plugins.

I've tried to edit the plugin with no luck also checked that the Mozilla plugin in registry is pointing to the java 7 which it is.

Pls HELP me.

Regards

Comment: Uh, if the browser is using the 32 bits runtime then that can only mean the browser is 32 bits too. Install the 32 bits Java 7 runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to Chrome menu > Settings.
Click Advanced Content settings.
Select Content settings... under the Privacy heading
Scroll down to find JavaScript, here you can enable or disable JavaScript